# Apache doesn't render .php files after installing ius php55u

Tags: apache-2.2, php, centos6.5

I've installed the IUS php55u on a CENTOS with virtualmin.

All the php sites are broken now. When I use test.php it gives me only the html code. If I try test.php5 it renders the PHP code.

Yet, in php.conf I have this line:

```
<FilesMatch \.php$>
    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
</FilesMatch>
```

That means it should render .php files and not php5. There are no other php.conf files on the server.

In httpd.conf all the handles are double (one for .php, one for .php5) but still only the php5 files are rendered.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you restart Apache?

Comment: Sure, too many times.

Comment: Any change I make to the quoted code destroys the rendering of php5 files as well. I can't seem to make it response with php to .php files any more....

Answer (score 0):

Well surprisingly - commenting out this FilesMatch section solve the problem !